# How to prevent Enter for onclick in anchor tag?

Tags: javascript

```
<a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="callFunction()"><img src="imagePath" border="0" alt="" title="" />
```

If i click the anchor tag it will call the function callFunction().
After clicking the anchor tag, if i press the enWter key, again the function is called.
How to prevent Enter for onclick in anchor tag?

Comment: try `javascript:void(0)`

Answer (score 2):

In your JS - you can call blur() which will 'un-focus' the link since it was clicked - Within callFunction():

```
$(anchorDomEl).blur()
```

Answer (score 0):

After clicking a link, it becomes focused.
You can remove the focus by using jQuery **[`blur()`](https://api.jquery.com/blur/)** function:

```js
var x = 0;

$("#link1").click(function() {
    $("#result").text(++x);
});

$("#link2").click(function() {
    $("#result").text(++x);
    $(this).blur();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="link1" href="#anchor">Message on enter after click</a> 
<br/>
<a id="link2" href="#anchor">No message on enter after click</a> 

<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function callFunction(e)
{
    if(e.keyCode==13)
        return false;
    // 13 is the keycode for enter key  , dont mind if the code is a bit wrong , but u got what i mean
    // your rest of the code
}

<a href='javascript:vois(0)' onclick='callFunction(event)'>your button</a>
```

explanation:  you can pass an event handler in the function "callFunction" and that event will trigger on every key pressed , so if the enter key is pressed , it triggers the functiona dn the keycode of enter key is 13 [enter key](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_event_key_keycode) , so when you press enter key , it will detect and return false , and the function will not execute further

Comment: Void not vois... And a little more explanation wouldn't hurt

Comment: Its not working. If i use this code, while click or enter both will accept the keyCode

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS:

```
:focus { outline: 0; } // or #targetID:focus { outline: 0; }
```

Using jQuery:

```
$('a').click(function () {
  this.blur(); // or $(this).blur();
});
```